# Carnot engine with draining reservoir?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat-engine

Two identical bodies of constant heat capacity $C$ at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively are used as
reservoirs for a heat engine. If the bodies remain at constant pressure, show that the amount of work
obtainable is
$$W =C(T_1 + T_2 − 2T_f )$$,
where $T_f$ is the final temperature attained by both bodies. Show that if the most efficient engine is
used, then 
$$T^2_f = T_1T_2$$

The first part I can do.  The heat engine is a carnot engine.  Let the heat into the engine be $Q_h$ and the heat out be $Q_l$.  The work output of the engine is
$$
W=Q_h-Q_l=C(T_1-T_f)-C(T_f-T_2)=C(T_1 + T_2 − 2T_f) 
$$

I don't see how to continue to the second part.

Answer (score 1):

If $T_f$ is the final temperature of the two bodies initially at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$, what is the change in entropy of each body?  What is the total change in entropy of these two reservoir bodies?  Since the change in entropy of the working fluid is equal to zero in a cycle, what is the total change in entropy of the combination of reservoir bodies and working fluid if the process is run reversibly?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract maximum work when the process is reversible. For any reversible process the net entropy generation is zero.